# Cosmonaut(CosmosDb) - problem with Serialization

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a POCO class as it has been shown below. What is that IFooInterface? it is an interface that each object whose wants to be added to Cosmosdb, needs to inherit from that. (The main reason back to this fact that we have a different type of Results)

```
[CosmosCollection("foo")]
public class FooClass 
{
    [CosmosPartitionKey]
    [JsonProperty("foo")] public string Foo{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")] public string Id{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reportSet")] public IFooInterface FooResult { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooInterface {}
```

and I have a repo who helps to get those results back. My problem is that in the method below, I got an error. Here is the method in a repo

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<objectClass>> GetAsync(GetObjects query)
    {
        try
        {
            var testOne= await _reportStore
                .Query(new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(query.foo) })
                .ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

And error is

> Message = "Could not create an instance of type IFooInterface. 
>      Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."
>   StackTrace = "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, 
>   JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)\r\n
>      at ...

I wonder how can I solve this issue? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

'The deserializer is not capable to resolve interfaces oder abstract classes. However a solution could be to add the `$type` property to your `FooResult` and use this for deserialization.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "reportSet", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects)]
public IFooInterface FooResult { get; set; }
```

Your Json object of FooResult has now to contain the `$type` property like

```
{ "$type" : "someNamespace.FooInterfaceImplementation, assemblyOfTheClass" }
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! that was what I ended up doing

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr I don't know how you implemented the $type but maybe the "Assembly-CSharp" on my Edit helps you as well.

Comment: I just added that attribute and it solved my problem with deserialization. I did not get your point, what do you mean by "Assembly-CSharp"

Comment: never mind, i had a missunderstanding on my own test